# How do I append a list recursively in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun foo (in i out)
    (if (>= i 0)
        (progn
            (append (list (intern (string (elt in i)))) out)
            (print output)
            (foo in (- i 1) out )
        )       
        (out)
    )
)

(print (foo "abcd" (- (length "abcd") 1) (list)))
```

I am trying to return this string as (a b c d). But it does return nil as output. What do I do wrong here? Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of basics wrong. Maybe you should read and work through an introductory book: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/   You can download the book for free as a PDF from there.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run the code? It doesn't do what you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just some minor mistakes. First, we need to get rid of `output` and `(output)`; these bear no relation to the code. It seems you were working with a variable called `output` and then renamed it to `out` without fixing all the code. Moreover, `(output)` is a function call; it expects a function called `output` to exist.

Secondly, the result of `append` must be captured somehow; in the `progn` you're just discarding it. Here is a working version:

```
(defun foo (in i out)
  (if (>= i 0)
    (foo in (1- i) (cons (intern (string (elt in i))) out))
    out))
```

Note also that instead of your `(append (list X) Y)`, I'm using the more efficient and idiomatic `(cons X Y)`.  The result of this `cons` operation has to be passed to `foo`. The `out` argument is our accumulator that is threaded through the tail recursion; it holds how much of the list we have so far.

I.e. we can't have `(progn <make-new-list> (foo ... <old-list>))`; that just creates the new list and throws it away, and then just passes the old list to the recursive call. Since the old list initially comes as `nil`, we just keep passing along this `nil` and when the index hits zero, that's what pops out. We need `(foo .... <make-new-list>)`, which is what I've done.

Tests:

```
[1]> (foo "" -1 nil)
NIL
[2]> (foo "a" 0 nil)
(|a|)
[3]> (foo "ab" 1 nil)
(|a| |b|)
[4]> (foo "abcd" 3 nil)
(|a| |b| |c| |d|)
[5]> (foo "abcd" 3 '(x y z))
(|a| |b| |c| |d| X Y Z)
```

Lastly, if you want the `(|a| |b| |c| |d|)` symbols to appear as `(a b c d)`, you have to fiddle  with`readtable-case`.

Of course:

```
[6]> (foo "ABCD" 3 nil)
(A B C D)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know what this has to do with appending. I think your desired output is also weird and you shouldn’t do what you’re doing. The right object for a character is a character not a symbol. Nevertheless, a good way to get the list `(a b c d)` is as follows:

```
CL-USER> '(a b c d)
```

Interning symbols at runtime is weird so maybe you would like this:

```
(defconstant +alphabet+ #(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z))

(defun foo (seq)
  (map 'list
       (lambda (char)
          (let ((index (- (char-code char) (char-code #\a))))
            (if (< -1 index (length +alphabet+))
                (svref +alphabet+ index)
                (error "not in alphabet: ~c" char))))
       seq))
```